# Why didn't David ascend into Heaven?

Tags: heaven, david

[Acts 2:34 NKJV](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts%202:34&version=NKJV):

> “For David did not ascend into the heavens, but he says himself: ‘ The
>   LORD said to my Lord,“ Sit at My right

Why didn't David ascend to heaven? Is this past tense? Is David in heaven now, or has he just never ascended into heaven all at?

Comment: I, personally, don't see any confusion in this verse.  If you read it in context, it seems to make perfect sense: [Acts 2:29-36](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts%202:29-36&version=NIV).

Comment: This is entirely too simplified, There are different answers depending upon whether we are considering physical bodies, Resurrection bodies, or souls and Spirits. There is also the consideration of whether or not Paradise and Heaven are the same, and then we also have to consider what 'the Kingdom of God refers to.

Comment: Please bring this old question into current site guidelines. Thanks. Resource for your convenience: [Question types that the community finds acceptable.](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3409/types-of-questions-or-template-questions-that-the-community-generally-finds-ac)

Comment: David didn’t ascend bodily like Yahushua (“Jesus”).  David’s body is still in the grave.

Answer (score 14):

This verse is contrasting Jesus and David. Jesus ascended:

> [Luke 24:51](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=luke%2024:51&version=NIV1984)
>
> While he was blessing them, he left them and was taken up into heaven.

David went to heaven the old fashioned way: by dying first.

This is evidenced by David's body being buried:

> [Acts 2:29](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts%202:29&version=NIV1984)
>
> “Brothers, I can tell you confidently that the patriarch David died and was buried, and his tomb is here to this day.

By contrast, Jesus was not "abandoned" (left) in the grave:

> [Acts 2:31](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts%202:31&version=NIV1984)
>
> Seeing what was ahead, he spoke of the resurrection of the Christ, that he was not abandoned to the grave, nor did his body see decay.

That David is in heaven is clear from [Hebrews 11:32-40](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=hebrews%2011:32-40&version=NIV1984). David is named in verse 32 with other faith heroes. Then in verse 40 it says, *"together with us would they be made perfect"* (since they can only be perfected in heaven).

Comment: While your answer is very good it only deals with the physical bodies, there is much much more to be considered here.

Answer (score 0):

Jesus did go to the bosom of Abraham and the scriptures do say they were set free. psalm 68:18
and Ephesians 4:8 also Matthew 57:52-53 speak of those who came out of the grave.
 The verse is speaking of Christ,that it would be Jesus who would ascend up and sit on the throne,not David.David was speaking prophetically of Jesus.
 David did not ascend to heaven,speaking of the one who would sit on the throne,he was speaking of Jesus.No one ascended till Jesus first ascended, then captivity was led to heaven meaning no one is no longer in the bosom of Abraham.

Comment: Welcome to the site! As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help), [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) and [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)

Answer (score 0):

The belief that one goes to heaven or hell immediately upon death is totally wrong. David has not ascended into Heaven because he is still dead and buried as Peter said. There's no need to twist his words to fit one's preconceived idea of what happens at death. There is no need to rely on a parable Jesus told abou the rich man and Lazarus. One cannot possibly think that you start living among Abraham's chest hairs when you die. The parable had a point and that point wasn't to teach what Heaven is like. No one ascends into Heaven (save for Enoch, Elijah and Moses) until the Lord returns with a shout and resurrects the dead as it says in 1 Thessalonians 4.

15 According to the Lord’s word, we tell you that we who are still alive, who are left until the coming of the Lord, will certainly not precede those who have fallen asleep. 16 For the Lord himself will come down from heaven, with a loud command, with the voice of the archangel and with the trumpet call of God, and the dead in Christ will rise first. 17 After that, we who are still alive and are left will be caught up together with them in the clouds to meet the Lord in the air. And so we will be with the Lord forever.

Ever wonder why the Bible refers to death as a sleep so many times? So and so "slept" with their fathers, etc. Because there is no awareness in death! It's like a dreamless sleep. "For the living know that they shall die, but the dead know not anything" Ecclesiastes 9:5.

Comment: Welcome. Please mention which denomination or group believe this way of interpretation. We do not welcome personal interpretations here.

Comment: Welcome to the site. As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help), [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) and [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Timothy is absolutely correct. Scripture makes it very clear we we do not go to heaven (or hell for that matter unless you a talking about the true meaning of the word hell - which is 'the grave') when we die.

There is so much evidence in scripture that we don't go to heaven when we die and so little to 'imply' that we do. I've always thought it a bit odd that if going to Heaven when you die is such a big thing in Christianity then why aren't the scriptures full of verses to confirm this?
The most common verse people use about going to Heaven when you die is when Christ said "Today you will be with me in Paradise" to which I ask the very obvious question.... was he? Christ was in the tomb for 3 days and 3 nights, so the criminal certainly wasn't in Heaven with him that day!!

No it's very simple really. We are clearly told that Christ is going to return and set up his Fathers Kingdom on EARTH. Doesn't even the Lord's Prayer tell us that Gods Kingdom is yet to come.....why would we need it to come if we went to heaven when we died?

Right in the first book of the bible we find out very clearly what happens to us when we die. "in the sweat of thy face shalt thou eat bread, till thou return unto the ground; for out of it wast thou taken: for dust thou art, and unto dust shalt thou return."  Genesis 3:19. No mention of a soul, spiritual, or resurrected body going to Heaven.

If David and all those other faithful men and women mentioned in the bible were in Heaven why wouldn't it mention as soon as they died 'they went to Heaven and are now with God'...,why? Because they aren't in Heaven at all, they are asleep awaiting the return of Christ. Hebrews 11 is saying they will be made perfect when WE ARE at the return of Christ. In other words they are asleep until the return of Christ, and it is only then when they shall truely receive the promise.

Gods plan is to be back here on Earth (when he will be 'all in all') but first he will send back His Son (who defeated the curse of death by never sinning) to set up His Kingdom, judge those who are found worthy of a place in that Kingdom and show the World that there is only One True God. But if you believe Jesus is God then that all gets a bit confusing doesn't it......a topic for another day.

1st Corinthians 15:52 In a moment, in the twinkiling of an eye, at the last trump: for the trumpet shall sound, and the dead shall be raised incorruptible, AND WE SHALL BE CHANGED.

Please study the bible and you will find this is the Truth. God's word makes sense, it doesn't matter what denomination you are, the Truth is there for everyone to read and understand.

'Seek Ye first the Kingdom of God.

Comment: This is entirely too simplified, There are different answers depending upon whether we are considering physical bodies, Resurrection bodies, or souls and Spirits. There is also the consideration of whether or not Paradise and Heaven are the same, and then we also have to consider what 'the Kingdom of God refers to. As you said the truth is there for everyone to read and share.

Comment: I thought the answer to the question was simple. David has not ascended to heaven.....that's what the bible says. It doesn't say his physical body, resurrected body, soul or spirit.

Comment: It woulld be except Jesus told the thief that he would be with him in paradise that day. The question then becomes if the thief went directly to Heaven why did David not?

Answer (score 0):

I think the confusion starts off when people believe that they are a spirit that has a soul that lives in a body. The bible clearly states we became a living soul and that to the dust we return, also states Jesus told his disciples he would come back for them. If they are in heaven now why would he come back for them. Bible also says that the corruptible must put on the incorruptible ( then shall be brought to pass the saying that is written, Death is swallowed up in victory.death, where is thy sting? O grave, where is thy victory?). Revelation also talks about the souls under the altar not directly in the presents of God. We say also say three people went to heaven but that isn't true. Why because we misunderstood what the bible said Enoch was (translated) metatithemi Hebrew-tranfered. Moses was buried,and Elijah wrote to a king 10 years later after he was taken into heaven which was the second heaven Jesus in John 3:13 Jesus says to Nicodemus, “No one has ever gone into heaven except the one who came from heaven–the Son of Man. We must understand Jesus is coming back for us and he is only coming back once. Lastly if Jesus is the example which by what will happen when he went back to heaven his body went with him.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE, you may benefit from reading this post on [what makes a good answer](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer) and this one concerning [what this site is about](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1379/what-christianity-stackexchange-is-and-more-importantly-what-it-isnt). As it stands this answer has a few problems for instance you say "The bible clearly states" - this site would want chapter and verse. It also contains a number of grammar errors that make parts of it difficult to understand.