# Were those who perished in the flood of Noah eternally damned?

Tags: bible, exegesis

The following passages from Genesis led me to think that all who perished at the time of Noah were cast into Sheol to await the great white throne judgment.

[Gen 6:5-7,17 KJV](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=genesis%206:5-17&version=KJV)

> <sup>5</sup>And GOD saw that the wickedness of man was great in the earth, and that every imagination of the thoughts of his heart was only evil continually.
>
> <sup>6</sup>And it repented the LORD that he had made man on the earth, and it grieved  him at his heart.
>
> <sup>7</sup>And the LORD said, I will destroy man whom I have created from the face of the earth; both man, and beast, and the creeping thing, and the fowls of the air; for it repenteth me that I have made them.
>
> <sup>17</sup>And, behold, I, even I, do bring a flood of waters upon the earth, to destroy all
> flesh, wherein is the breath of life, from under heaven; and every thing that is in the
> earth shall die.

What do theologians say about it?

Comment: It's worth noting that not all Christians believe the Flood was a literal global event.  Personally, **I*** do, but many believe it's allegorical, or perhaps a local flood.  I presume you'd like to limit answers to those that hold to the literal interpretation because this question will only make sense in the context of those Christians holding to a literal interpretation.

Comment: I think this is an interesting and well posed question, +1.

Comment: Also, questions regarding *eternal damnation* should be always taken seriously from the community.

Comment: @ David Stratton I will concede that there are many who do not believe that the Flood was global, but I must direct your attention to Genesis 1:6  And God said, Let there be a firmament in the midst of the waters, and let it divide the waters from the waters. How hard would it be for God who caused the dry ground to emerge from the Seas to reverse that? and if I may also point out that God said he was going to kill all into which he had breathed the breath of life. To me it means that it has to have been Global. But I was wrong one other time in the last 75 years.

Comment: @CecilBeckum - I take it you missed the part where I said that personally, I believe it?  No problem...  I'm in agreement with you, I just left the comment to help clarify what perspectives you're interested in so that the answers you get are more geared toward what you're looking for.  And one other time in the last 75 years - LOL -  You sound like me!

Comment: @CecilBeckum: 1) It's not a question of "how hard would it be"--if the flood, or creation, was a test of God's abilities, creation would have been instantaneous. 2) The same people who believe in either a local or allegorical flood, are the same ones who believe in an allegorical creation account.

Comment: In any case, I have edited the question to side-step the issue of global vs. local flood--I think it still asks the question as intended.

Comment: There's also those who believe it literally covered the erets (world), versus those to believe it literally covered the erets (country, inhabited region).

Comment: God gives everyone plenty of chances to repent. I don't know about you, but if I had been ridiculing Noah for hundreds of years, and suddenly I was about to drown in a the flood I had disbelieved, I would certainly be repenting!

Comment: @ Byzantine I'm sure we would, but that was a judgment by God and one thing is very clear in the Bible that you may have a multitude of chances to repent prior to judgment, there are none after judgment. Check out the sayings of Jesus and the Revelation.

Comment: "God is compassionate!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting that it is *that passage* that leads you to the conclusion that *" all who perished at the time of Noah were cast into Sheol to await the great white throne judgment"*. I say that because there is *another* passage which *explicitly agrees with your conclusion!*

> For if God did not spare angels when they sinned, but sent them to hell, **putting them in chains of darkness to be held for judgment; if he did not spare the ancient world when he brought the flood on its ungodly people, but protected Noah, a preacher of righteousness, and seven others;** if he condemned the cities of Sodom and Gomorrah by burning them to ashes, and made them an example of what is going to happen to the ungodly; and if he rescued Lot, a righteous man, who was distressed by the depraved conduct of the lawless (for that righteous man, living among them day after day, was tormented in his righteous soul by the lawless deeds he saw and heard) – if this is so, then the Lord knows how to rescue the godly from trials and **to hold the unrighteous for punishment on the day of judgment.**

[2 Peter 2:4-9](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Peter%202:4-9&version=NIVUK)

We don't know for sure if they were *eternally damned* - only that they are being held for judgement. However, it is logical to think that they were / will be damned because they are being *"held for punishment"* and because they did not [go to heaven when they died](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/20023/saints-in-heaven/20043#20043).